# Excel MIN and MAX function not consistent across worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

This Excel formula works OK when entered on the same worksheet as the target range of data but returns 0 when inserted in any other sheet in the same workbook.

```
=MIN(INDIRECT((ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(EventID_2_Start)),COLUMN(TopTemp), 1, 1) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(EventID_2_End)),COLUMN(BtmTemp), 1, 1))))
```

I have an equivalent `MAX` function which gives the same result.
If I strip the `MIN/MAX` function of the formula and place anywhere in the workbook I get the correct range reference i.e. `$D$1442:$F$1541`

The range names all have workbook scope and refer to other sheets than the one with the data. I can't see what else I can qualify to make the `MAX/MIN` function work correctly on other sheets, i.e I have the data on sheet `Raw Data` and I want to display the `MAX` & `MIN` on sheet `Results`.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that you can't use this formula to work when data is in other sheet this is because you can't use `$D$1442:$F$1541` in your range, you need to point the sheet also, so you want something like that: `'Raw Data'$D$1442:$F$1541`.
This said, you need to modify your formula in the `ADDRESS` section for something like this:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT((ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(EventID_2_Start)),COLUMN(TopTemp), 1, 1,"Raw Data") & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(EventID_2_End)),COLUMN(BtmTemp), 1, 1))))
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding the `ADDRESS` function's `[sheet_text]` parameter and I still get a `#REF!` error, when the formula is on the Result sheet. If I remove the outer `MIN` and `INDIRECT` functions the correct range reference is returned as `'Raw Data'!$D$1442:'Raw Data'!$F$1541`

Comment: Of course it's error. You need `'Raw Data'!$D$1442:$F$1541` instead of `'Raw Data'!$D$1442:'Raw Data'!$F$1541`. See the formula in my answer.

Comment: I was convinced it was important to qualify both limits of the range address with the `[sheet_text]` when accessing another worksheet, clearly not. Sorry I missed this in your answer, thanks.